# Button not clickable - android

Tags: android, wordpress, button, onclick

I have a button on a banner in my home page. When I hit that button it will redirect to contact us page when in full screen. But the button is not clickable when accessing the page from an android phone. Any idea in resolving this?

Comment: why not?? post some code...

Comment: chances are you have given only one background  image for button or doing some thread work on the button click

Comment: Please add your code without showing what you have doing in code no one can solve your problem.

Comment: Its a wordpress project. So I have added revolutionary slider. I have just inserted a button. There is not onclick function here.

Comment: <a class="tp-button orange small" href="/contact">Get Started Now </a>

Comment: Please can anyone help me? I have been using revolution slider plugin version 3.0.95.

Answer (score 0):

it might not help much, but did you try giving "alert" in your button action? Just to check whether, the onclick function is getting executed?

Comment: This should be comment.